# How can I use Node.js in Netsuite?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, netsuite, amazon-mws

So I have been fiddling around with Netsuite and I want to know if it is possible to use Node.js or npm modules within a SuiteScript or Suitelet?

My goal is to use a few npm modules within Netsuite to interact with Amazon's MWS API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's a different Javascript engine. Rhino I believe.

You can use various JS libraries but Node modules are usually written with that engine in mind.

Comment: Correct. I believe NetSuite's server-side is running Rhino 1.7. You cannot run node-based code on NetSuite; however, you can write your code as, say, an npm module, and run npm scripts from the command line. I have done this in the past for unit testing, doc generation, eslint, etc. In order to actually run code in NetSuite, though, it must be in a plain .js file that NetSuite can interpret and load as a Library on your Script record.

Comment: Thank you @TonyH and erictgrubaugh. Though I did read something about Node.js in SuiteCommerce. If you have a NetSuite account you can see that [here](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4183925632.html). It talks about downloading Node.js to use for SuiteCommerce. Is that a completely different system?

Comment: What I have decided to do is use npm modules to interact with Netsuite but that won't do the whole job. Therefore a script will have to be made on Netsuite's side as well.

Comment: Yeah,  that's typically the case.  Its a bummer bc it's harder to do source control for the NS server side stuff